# Get The First Value In A Row "On Clicking" And Pass To Controller

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, phalcon

I am working on PHP Phalcon.

I have a view with a table. The table has a dynamic number of rows. I want to click on a row and get the value in the first column. Here is my html table:

```
<?php
        $counter = count($prescriptions);
        $i = 0;
        if ($counter == 0 )
        { echo "You have no earlier prescriptions." ;}
        else {
        ?>

<Table class="inbox_table" cellspacing="0" style="width: 998px">
    <tr>
        <td class="inbox_table_cell inbox_table_heading">ID</td>
        <td class="inbox_table_cell inbox_table_heading">Doctor ID</td>
        <td class="inbox_table_cell inbox_table_heading">Patient Name</td>
        <td class="inbox_table_cell inbox_table_heading">Ailment</td>
        <td class="inbox_table_cell inbox_table_heading">Date</td>
    </tr>

    <?php
            While ($i < $counter)
            {
            ?>
    <tr onclick="">
        <td class="inbox_table_cell" id="ID"><?php echo $prescriptions[$i]->ID;  ?></td>
        <td class="inbox_table_cell" id="Doc_ID"><?php echo $prescriptions[$i]->Doctor_ID;  ?></td>
        <td class="inbox_table_cell" id="P_Name"><?php echo $patient_name;  ?></td>
        <td class="inbox_table_cell" id="Ailment"><?php echo $prescriptions[$i]->Ailment; ?></td>
        <td class="inbox_table_cell" id="Date"><?php echo $prescriptions[$i]->Date_;  ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
            $i++;
            }
            }
            ?>
</Table

>
```

Here is the associated Action Method:

```
public function PrescriptionTableAction(){
    //Select the earlier prescriptions of the online patient.

    $current_PID = $this->session->current_patient_ID;

    $get_prescriptions = "Select Doctor_ID,Patient_ID,Ailment,ID,Date_ from Prescriptions where Patient_ID = '$current_PID'";
    $this->view->prescriptions = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($get_prescriptions);

    $this->view->patient_name = $this->session->current_patient->Full_Name;
}
```

What I want to do:

In abstraction, when I click on a row in the table, it opens up a view of the complete prescription with the names of the medicines and the instructions for each medicine, the name of the doctor who wrote the prescription and so on.

More specifically, when I click on a row, I want to get the value of the row from the "ID" column. (It corresponds to the primary key in the database of the prescriptions table). I want to pass this value to another action method in the same controller where the details of the prescription can be fetched from the database and then displayed in the corresponding view.

I have read similar problems and solutions on this website, but almost all solutions have offered "alerts". I want to pass the value back to the controller, how can I do that?

Comment: but ajax is javascript

Comment: Editted my question. I am not particularly experienced in scripting. I noticed people offer "Js" and "AJAX" solutions separately under separate headings.

Comment: You can pass it as a param in http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ the `$.ajax()` method, since it seems you're using jQuery. Specifically looking at examples near the bottom `$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/controller/view/",
  data: { id: $(this).find('td:first').text() }, success: doStuff()
})` to send the data to your controller Your controller should then return partial html, as opposed to a full page and you can update some sort of container div/element with the returned data using a `doStuff()` method. You can display the full view if you want, but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Actually I am using JavaScript. Or atleast I am trying to. Anyway I have figured out a way to pass the value to the action method as a parameter like so: `window.location.href = "ViewPrescription?id=" + id; ` now I want to figure out how to get the value from the first column.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem in the way that I wanted to; using simple javascript.

This is my script function:

```
function func(e){
var id = e.target.parentNode.firstElementChild.innerText;
            window.location.href = "ActionMethod?id=" + id;
 }
```

And in the view I made this edit:

```
 <tr onclick="func(event)">
...
</tr>
```

And this solved my problem!